# Transform date format in R

Tags: r, date

I am datamining the data from a mobile application,
I have a simple problem that is reccurring that is giving me trouble,

```
Database

UserId         Platform         Date
1              Android          01-01-2016
2              iOS              02/01/2016
3              Android          03-01-2016
4              Android          04-01-2016
```

As you can see the format of the date is different depending whether the user is on using iOS or Android,

My question, is there a way to transform the Android format date to d/m/y instead of d-m-y ? Directly in the Date column or by creating a new one,

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

If you want to convert both types of strings directly to a date you could use the `dmy()` function in the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)

date.vector <- c("01-01-2016", "02/01/2016", "03-01-2016", "04-01-2016")

dmy(date.vector)

# > dmy(date.vector)
# [1] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-04"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `gsub` to replace dashes by slashes:

```
gsub("-", "/", mydata$Date)
```

Comment: Careful though that in Europe we use (among others) dd-mm-YYYY, while in the US it's mm/dd/YYYY. Just replacing dashes by slashes can cause problems.

Comment: Hi lebatsnok, when I apply the command it is giving me a new "value" instead of a new "dataframe"... Any idea why ?
Thanks

Comment: Great to hear. Please also think about others: It would be helpful for others who find your questions through Google if you post your answer or accept one of the provided answers that you did apply. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work